# Appending an option between two options using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, append

I need to append an option between two options.I have found so many answers regarding appending an option using jquery.But there the option is appending to the last.But i need to be between two options.

I need to insert the new option between `2` & `3`. How can I do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var option = $('<option disabled="disabled" value="">-------------------------</option>');
  $('#country').append(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option value='1'>1</option>
  <option value='2'>2</option>
  <option value='3'>3</option>
  <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by using `insertAfter()` and targeting the `option` by its index with `:eq()`:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var $option = $('<option disabled="disabled" value="">-------------------------</option>');
  $option.insertAfter('#country option:eq(1)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Or alternatively you could select the target by its value:

```
$option.insertAfter('#country option[value="2"]');
```

Or you could use `insertBefore()` and select the third element instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Apart from the question can i insert a <hr> instead of --------- as option

Comment: No. Only `<option>` and `<optgroup>` elements can be children of a `select`. Not a `<hr />`

Answer (score 1):

Try `.after()` or `.before()` depending on what your reference point is.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var option = $('<option disabled="disabled" value="">-------------------------</option>');
    $('#country option[value="2"]').after(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>

</select>
```